# Почему не работает код на мобильном телефоне? Перепробовал уже все

Tags: javascript, html

При нажатии на кнопку плей звук запускается на всех устройствах на этой странице https://workinbooth.com/page26261983.html .
Но дальше если выбирать где проигрывать `Insde` или `Outside` кнопка работает только на десктопе, не понимаю почему, помогите пожалуйста.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  myAudio = document.getElementById("bg-sound");
  let fadeTime = 3; //Врямя смены иконок
  myAudio.volume = 0.9; //Задаём громкость
  
  $(".inside").hide();

  $(".outside").click(function(e) {
    myAudio.volume = 0.01;
    $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime);
    $(".inside").fadeIn(fadeTime);
  });

  $(".inside").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();
    myAudio.volume = 0.9; 
    $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime);
    $(".outside").fadeIn(fadeTime);
  });

  $("#bg-sound").on("ended", function() {
    $(".inside").fadeOut(fadeTime);
    $(".outside").fadeIn(fadeTime);
  });

});
```